# Multiple parquet files have a different data type for 1-2 columns

Tags: python, pyspark, schema, parquet

I'm trying to read different parquet files into one dataframe using Pyspark and it's giving me errors because some columns in multiple parquet files have columns with different data types. Like for example:
The column "geo" has a data type "Double" in some files and "String" in others.

How should I approach this? Do I have to manually cast every column with different data type in multiple parquet files?

Answer (score 4):

**Background**

I was struggling with a very similar issue at work. I had an audit folder where each file had the same column names, but the Date column was a StringType rather than a TimestampType.

For background, I'm originally a C# developer and I have started using Azure Synapse Analytics. I am fairly new to using Pyspark so I spent a couple days on this problem, looking around but I was struggling to find anything.I eventually figured out a solution on my own, so I thought I'd come back to give guidance to you or to any future developers who are in a pickle.

**Solution**

Firstly, I defined the schema that matched the columns of my newer and correct files.

```
schema = StructType([,
    StructField("Date", TimestampType(), False),
    StructField("PipelineName", StringType(), False),
    StructField("SourceFileName", StringType(), False),
    StructField("ActivityName", StringType(), True),
    StructField("InsertedRows", LongType(), True),
    StructField("FailedRows", LongType(), True),
    StructField("Message", StringType(), True)])
```

I then created a blank dataframe with the schema I just created.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(), schema)
```

Then I iterated through every file that was in my audit directory.

```
auditDir = "DirectoryNameHere"
for f in mssparkutils.fs.ls(auditDir)
```

Within my for loop, I used the directory name and the file name to create the file path.

I create a new dataframe that reads this file's path using a withColumn that looks at the Date column, and converts it to a timestamp. This seems to work whether the column is a StringType or a TimestampType.

I presume something similar can be done to convert your strings into doubles.

Because all my parquet files have identical columns, I have just used the union method rather than unionByName, and this joins this file's data onto an ever growing dataframe.

```
path = os.path.join(auditDir, f.name)
newDf = spark.read.parquet(path).withColumn("Date", to_timestamp(col("Date")))    
df = df.union(newDf)
```

For my purposes, I am then writing these out as one partition in order of the oldest date first. This new partition is then written to the same folder. However, I would recommend if you can to write to another folder and keep your old files as a backup.

```
df.orderBy(col("Date")).coalesce(1).write.mode("append").parquet(auditDir)
```

While iterating over files isn't ideal, this has been the only way I have found. Thankfully, my data size was small so it did not take too long.

Thanks for reading, I hope this helps you and others a lot

-Josh

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not posted any specific dataset. I am taking below example to show you how things actually function when comes to reading multiple parquet/dataframe to a single dataframe -

**Case where a Schema is passed before reading the data**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

list_1 = [[1,"item 1" , 2],[2 ,"item 2", 3],[1 ,"item 3" ,2],[3 ,"item 4" , 5]]
list_2 = [[1,"item 1",2],[3 ,"item 4",2],[4 ,"item 4",4],[5 ,"item 5",2]]

my_schema = StructType([StructField("Item_ID",IntegerType(), True),StructField("Item_Name",StringType(), True ),StructField("Quantity",IntegerType(), True)])
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(list_1, my_schema)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(list_2, my_schema)

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")
```

Here, you can see I am passing a schema when reading into the df. In your case it will be from parquet files.

Now, if I wish to read both data frames above into a single dataframe, I have the ensurity that both the DFs have same schema for all the respective columns.

Hence, below code will work -

```
 df3 = df2.union(df1)
```

But in your case, it does not. So, to avoid this, you need to make sure that each column in both parquet should be of same type. So what you can do is, read both parquets in two different dataframes and infer schema to compare it.

Once you have the info of the columns that have a type mismatch, you can type cast and then perform **union()** operation as above to read the data in single DF.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for answering. I just have one little query. I have close to 1900 parquet files with each having 383 columns and 393 million rows. So how do I find which files contain columns with different data types?

Comment: Can I pass a custom schema by doing `spark.read.schema(schema).parquet('path/to/file/')` while reading all the parquet files into one dataframe? Will different data types for certain columns be automatically converted to custom schema?

Comment: @SubhransuNanda for figuring out the data types of column sin each parquet, you can use printSchema() method on your dataframe. This will print the column name and its inferred data type and then you can identify which columns have diff type compared to other data frames

Comment: @SubhransuNanda, yes you can pass a custom schema but that does not necessarily mean it will automatically type cast for you. For example, if the column holds string as - Y, N and you expect it to be boolean type.

Comment: @SubhransuNanda can you accept this one as an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but wondering:  what if you just cast all columns as `string` when you read in.  Then after everything is read in cast columns to the appropriate type as defined say in a separate dictionary.  This way you can read in everything regardless of type an establish a suitable universal schema after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is catch the exception and handle it based on the column and cast appropriately. You could also read all schema metadata and unify them, then read all files with the unified schema specified.